# Android AlertDialog Size Theme

Tags: android, styles, themes, size, android-alertdialog

After adding a theme to my AlertDialog it got very small. How to change the size of the dialog to default?

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to resise the dialog.

After invoking `build()` method on `AlertDialog.Builder`, you can invoke:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);
```

where 600, 400 is the width and height of it.

Or if you would like to set it to screen, follow this code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
alertDialogd.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```